# Android: Design "HELP" for App

Tags: android

How people usually design HELP for there applications ?
I know that good idea can be video...with button skip...
What else ? How to implement some slides ? Because I don't want to use just simple dialog with a text...I need to use some pictures...Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used HTML and a webview in the past. Essentially: create a help website, store it in the assets folder, access via activity with webview. This will allow for text,images,links, organization, formatting, feedback email, and just about anything else a help file would need.